# Why Spark Fails for Huge Dataset with Container Getting Killed Issue and Hive works

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to run a Simple Query Assuming running queries with spark.sql("query") compared to Dataframes has no performance Difference as I am using Spark 2.1.0 i have Catalyst Optimizer to take care of the optimization part & Tungsten Enabled.

Here i am joining 2 tables with a Left-Outer join. My 1st table is 200 GB & is the Driving table(being on left side) and the 2nd table is 2GB and there has to be no Filters as per our Business requirement.

Configuration of My Cluster. **As this is Shared Cluster i have a assigned a specific queue which allows me to use 3-TB of Memory(Yes 3 tera bytes) but the No.of VCORES is 480** . That means i can only run 480 Parallel tasks. On top of that AT YARN LEVEL i have a Constraint to having MAX of 8 cores per node. And MAX of 16 GB of Container Memory Limit. **Because of which i cannot give my Executor-Memory(which is per node) more than 12 GB as i am giving 3-GB as ExecutorMemoryOverhead to be on safer side which becomes 15 GB of per node memory utilization.**

**So after calculating 480 total allowed vcores with 8-cores per node limit i have got 480/8 = 60 Nodes for my computation. Which comes to 60*15 = 900 GB of usable memory(I don't why total queue memory is assigned 3 TB) And this is at peak .. IF i am the only one using the Queue but that's not always the case.**

**Now the doubt is how Spark this whole 900 GB of memory. From the Numbers & stats i can clearly say that my Job will run without any issues as the data size i am trying to process is just 210-250 GB MaX & i have 900 GB of available memory.**

But i keep getting Container getting killed error msgs. And i cannot increase the YARN Container size becoz it is at YARN level and overall cluster will get the increased container size which is not the right thing. I have also tried Disabling vmem-check.enabled property to FALSE in my code using sparksession.config(property) but that doesn't help too May be i am not allowed to change anything at YARN Level so it might be ignoring that.

Now on what basis spark splits the data initially is it based on the Block size defined at Cluster Level (assuming 128 MB) I am thinking this because when my Job is started i see that my Big Table which is of around 200 GB has 2000 tasks so on what basis Spark calculates this 2000 tasks(partitions) I thought may be the Default partition size when spark starts to load my table is quite big by seeing the Input Size/Records && Shuffle Write Size/Records Under the Stage Tab of Spark UI and that is the reason why i am getting Container Killed Error & suggestion to increase Executor memory overhead which did not helped either.

**I tried to Repartition the Data from 10k to 100k partitions and tried persisting to MEMORY_ONLY, MEMORY_AND_DISK, DISK_ONLY but nothing Helped. Many of my task were getting failed and at the End job used to get Fail. Sometimes with Container killed, Direct Buffer, and others.**

**Now here what is the use of Persist /Caching and how does it behave ..???? I am doing**

```
val result = spark.sql("query big_table").repartition(10000, $<column name>).persist()
```

The column in Repartition is the Joining key so it gets distributed. TO make this work before the JOIN i am doing result.show(1) . So the action is performed and data gets persisted on DISK and Spark will read data persisted on DISK for JOIN and there will be no load on memory as it is stored in small chunks on Disks(Am i correct over HERE ..??)

Why in HIVE this same job with the same Big Table plus some additional tables with Left Join get completed. Though it takes time but it completes successfully But it Fails in Spark..?? Why ?? Is Spark not the Complete Replacement of HIVE..?? Doesn't Spark works like HIVE when it comes to Spilling to Disk & write data to disk while using DISK for PERSISTING.

**Does yarn-container size plays a role if we have less container size but good number of nodes ??**

**Does Spark combines memory of all the available nodes (15 GB Per Node as per container size) and Combine them to load a large partition..??**

Comment: Can Anybody please answer this ..??